# Showing error page when an unhandled exception raised in JSP page

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

I am using tiles in my struts 1.x application.
and for error handling i have added below code in my web.xml

```
<error-page>  
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>  
  <location>/pages/error.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

When an unhandled exception raises in Action class, it shows up configured error.jsp which is fine.
but if exception is raised in jsp page (which is tile body) then error.jsp comes in place of tile body. but my requirement is to display error page replacing total tile definition.

Could some one please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the tiles attributes before the body attribute have already been rendered (written to stream). It's normal AFAIK to expect to land on dedicated error pages when the exception is thrown from a jsp element.

But you still have options. You could take the error message and redirect to the error page. Or write the error page so that it overlays the partially rendered page.